# Where to store a props type declaration on a DDD project?

Tags: vue.js, interface, frontend, domain-driven-design, vue-composition-api

I am trying to apply DDD to a Vue project (so it's DDD on the frontend) and I have a doubt as to where store a props type. A Vue component can have `props`, which is basically named data passed to the component. Most of my components that work as a page are stored inside the `application` folder, because they manage all the data flux, that is, the repositories that make API calls, instanciating domain classes, etc. For each of these `application` components, I have a `.ts` file that speciafies its props; so together with my `Profile.vue`, I have a `ProfileProps.ts`.

`Profile.vue`: the props being defined

```
import type { ProfileProps } from './ProfileProps'

const props = defineProps<ProfileProps>()
```

The props type inside `ProfileProps.ts`

```
export type ProfileProps = {
  user: IBackendUser
}
```

As you can see, there's only one prop and it's also typed as what I expect the backend to pass to my component: the user. My question is, where should I keep this interface of mine `IBackendUser`: maybe a folder in the application called `interfaces`, or maybe put it in the `domain` folder?

PS.: I have a separate file for the props because some components have extense props (big objects), and I want to keep the pattern for all the project.

Comment: IIRC this would be a footgun because script setup doesn't play well with external types, types have to be statically analyzed with defineProps macro

Comment: The "type" is actually an interface, and I am using a library for Vite + Vue to make those work :)

Comment: Maybe is not the time to take that decision, what about add a `.ts` file named `entities.ts`  with those interfaces.

I'll suggest to use just `type User` avoid `IBackendUser`, the presentation layer shouldn't know that detail, an that interface should response to what the presentation layer needs. Later you could make those decisions, if you are not sure right know it's good to delay it.

Comment: @rigojr Well, I do get what you're saying, but my case is a bit different. I've been working with DDD as a way to organize code in the frontend, so, for example, I have a `Form.ts` inside entities < Login < domain, because it represents what the login form should do, generally speaking (like validation, clearing errors, asigning error to specific fields). You wouldn't consider this business logic, but as I said, applying DDD to the frontend made me think that's a good ideia; and it does seem good, but it has some difficult decisions like this one.

Comment: What do you mean by DDD? DDD is a philosophy of designing and solving business problems that contains multiple patterns and best practices that help to tackle the complexities of a domain.

Comment: If by DDD, you mean domain model pattern, it still focuses on how to separate consistency boundaries and make aggregates to design a good solution.

Comment: If by DDD, you mean using rich domain objects against anemic domain objects, it makes sense. Because what you want to reuse in the front end is behaviors around the domain objects. But make sure that the logic is encapsulated in your domain objects (which makes it easier to reuse the logic of your domain models) not your UI components. UI components should contain references to domain objects.

Answer (score 1):

> A Vue component can have `props`, which is basically named data passed to the component.

Simple, do it as you would do without DDD.

DDD applies to domain models and logic, not to views and view related components.

Comment: Well, the idea is to USE DDD, since there's a bit of domain logic in the frontend and because there are some concepts that do apply.

Comment: Yea, but DDD is not meant for UI components, neither is MVVM (similar pattern). When you apply DDD it **MUST** be UI and persistence ignorant. If you have to incorporate UI concerns or database concerns into your models and domain, you are doing it wrong and its not DDD anymore. Persistence is abstracted away behind repositories and UI by components and application services (application services don't contain business logic, only application logic, such as navigation, UI-near validation, auto-completing etc.). Also, domain models are classes with logic. You use interfaces which cant have logic

Comment: Trying to apply MVVM and/or DDD to application logic and UI was one of the biggest things I was struggling with at the beginning, but once you realize it, that it's not meant for this sections, it becomes very clear and easy to work with it. If you continue to enforce DDD on UI components and view logic, you will only keep running into bigger and bigger walls and end up in a mess. It still maybe be valid to apply it in some parts of the UI, but these must be completely decoupled from the UI components

Comment: Depending on your framework there may be a bias against this (i.e. angular/vue approach may count there) and you would to have to do a lot of extra code to accomplish this. i.e. angular has a bias to writing logic in components, trying to outsource that to domain models may prove difficult as you would have to write a lot lot more boilerplate code to make it work with angulars binding and change tracking capabilities same as trying to apply DDD to Unity3Ds component model will just drive you insane with tons of bad working boilerplate.

Comment: But the general rule of thumb is, that frontend/UI doesn't contain business logic, only input validation and application logic (navigating the views, state management), even on desktop application where business logic and application logic are in the same context (executable)